# Fetching web page links from a website and iterating through those links to fetch further information

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a absolute beginner to Python Programming .I am practicing web scraping on some websites using bs4 module in Python.

Here I want to fetch the links from the website and then iterate through them because when we open each of the links on the website it goes to a new web page from there I want to extract the agent names. Now there are many links, so I have tried to extract them into a list first and then iterate through them. But my list is returning empty list.
Kindly tell where I am doing wrong and what should be done.

`````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://www.mcgrath.com.au/offices', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')

links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.align w-1140 p-none a')]
print(links) ````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector. Instead you should be using: `.align.w-1140.p-none > a`. Like:

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.align.w-1140.p-none > a') if item['href'] != '/']
```

It's because `<div class="align w-1140">` matches with joined CSS classes.

And then to get the agents emails you can do:

```
res = requests.get('https://www.mcgrath.com.au/offices/178-annerley-yeronga', headers = {'User-agent': 'Super Bot 9000'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
agents_mails = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.agent a[href^=mailto]')]
```

Comment: Yes I have tried ````links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.align w-1140 p-none a')]
 ```` but still returning empty list.

Comment: @ag2019 no, read my answer carefully. There are no spaces between `.align`, `.w-1140` and `.p-none`

Comment: Ok sorry I overlooked it. But it is giving every ````href````` tags, I just want the links to the new webpages. How can it be scraped? Kindly if you could suggest.

Comment: @ag2019 I'm not sure I undertstand what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: ````C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/laptop/PycharmProjects/myproject/McGrath.py
['/', '/', '/buy', '/rent', '/sell', '/sell#_mg_find_expert_b', '/offices', '/home-loans', '/mcgrath-support', '/about', '/offices/178-annerley-yeronga', 'tel:+61 7 3892 9200', '/offices/34-avalon',...]
Process finished with exit code 0
 ```` It is extracting the contact numbers, links and other attribute having the tag href, but I want to have only the links and iterate each of the them to fetch agent name, email which is inside the respective link.

Comment: Kindly suggest something if possible.

Comment: @ag2019, I provided an update in the answer on how to get only the direct `a` child's href's excluding the `/`.

Comment: @ag2019 I exemplified also how to get the mails of the agents.

Comment: Yes it works , thanks  a lot. Kindly could you just explain me the edit which you made? Another thing, now if I iterate through these links can I access the agent name , contact no. and email address directly?

Comment: @ag2019 in the last code snippet you can see that I'm fetching for one of the pages (`/offices/178-annerley-yeronga`) got in the first request. On it you have those agents with their photos and emails, each agent being a `div` with a CSS class `.agent` What I basically do is select all `.agent`'s and then extract the `href`'s that have a `mailto` in them.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining , but if it will take a very long time to explicitly fetch for all the pages. If I want to fetch for all the pages then what should be done if you could kindly suggest.

Comment: @ag2019 multiprocessing

Comment: If i write ````for i in links:
    agents_names = [item['href'] for item in i.find_all('.bottom h5')]
print(agents_names)```` This is not allowing me to extract all the agent names from all the pages, but I have iterated them all. Kindly if possible suggest.

Comment: After adding the above code it is displaying the error:````File "C:/Users/laptop/PycharmProjects/myproject/McGrath.py", line 11, in <module>
    agents_names = [item['href'] for item in i.find_all('.bottom h5')]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all' ```` If possible kindly suggestwhat can be done?

Comment: Let's move the discussion over here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191682/discussion-between-andreihondrari-and-ag2019

Comment: I have asked some question in the chat room. Kindly if possible see to it and tell where am I doing wrong and what should be done.